# URL ISSUE with PHP

Tags: php, apache, document-root

I would like to explain my situation the best I could because some of the terms that I would user here may not make sense to you you can always ask for clarity.

here I am using require_once like this (way 1)

```
require_once('../../model/_constants.php');
```

The above require once work fine but when I change this to the following (way 2):

```
require_once('/claimspro/model/class.session.php');
```

it throw the following error

```
Warning: require_once(/claimspro/model/class.session.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\claimspro\public\admin\html_included\all_require_once_files.php on line 4
```

I know this is the right path here is the image that shows the path

[image]

I am doing this because when I upload this to server the way 1 does not work so when i change to way to it works fine on godaddy server but not my localhost...

Any Idea

Comment: it would be `/www/claimspro/model/class.session.php` or maybe even `/wamp/www/claimspro/model/class.session.php`

Comment: Relative paths should always work the same way. That's why they exist.

Comment: @andrew let me try that (tried didn't work same error) :(

Comment: Yes 2nd one worked @andrew

Comment: @Sharif ok, but if i were you id stick with the relative path otherwise everything will break when you move it to your online server

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` so you don't have to specify the document root manually.

Comment: @andrew I also like that path but as I mentioned I am doing this for godaddy if you could tell how to change setting their for relative path

Comment: @Sharif way1 would be fine but the best way is as antony suggests, `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and you'll see how it should be done

Comment: thank you @Antony and @andrew i like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use full path to `/wamp/www/claimspro/model/`